# I keep encountering this error when trying to create multiple pages in app.js - what to do?

Tags: react-router, jsx

I am trying to make a portfolio website (using React codesandbox) with multiple pages that talk about me, and I encountered an error message stating "Element type is invalid" in my React application. This error typically occurs when trying to render a component that is either not defined or not exported properly.

In my code snippet, the error occurs in the App component when rendering routes using React Router. I don't know how I can successfully debug this error. Can someone help me understand what had happened and what can I do to correct this error? Thank you for taking your time on this.

[Screenshot of error message in codesandbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8svbi.png)

`App.js`

```
// App.jsx
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Landing from "./pages/landing";
import List from "./pages/toc";
import About from "./pages/about";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
          <Route path="/table-of-contents" component={List} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I have tried to debug which Route is messing up the code but it comes up that the Route itself is flawed. I don't know the exact steps to accomplish the react-router-dom page creation.

P.S.: Here is the link to a forked [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/portoflio-forked-h78wgk?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltyrrimn0006356bizn2cuh8%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltyrrimn0002356bteiuoc5n%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltyrrimn0003356bhck1u0e0%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltyrrimn0005356ba62wu4tl%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cltyrrimn0002356bteiuoc5n%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltyrrimn0002356bteiuoc5n%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltyzod960002356bey5k1utq%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A6%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A36%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A6%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A41%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu01cv130002356b3c3u9297%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A3%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A22%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A3%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A22%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fpages%252Ftoc.jsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clu01cv130002356b3c3u9297%2522%257D%252C%2522cltyrrimn0005356ba62wu4tl%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltyrrimn0004356b6tviuqmm%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltyrrimn0005356ba62wu4tl%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltyrrimn0004356b6tviuqmm%2522%257D%252C%2522cltyrrimn0003356bhck1u0e0%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltyrrimn0003356bhck1u0e0%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) page:

Comment: We can't really address issues in code we can't see. Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with here? If you've a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) can you also share a link to it so we can inspect it live?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I have edited to include the link to the codesandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odd, normally you should have seen an error stating something to the effect of "Switch not exported from `react-router-dom`, these are the named exports ....". Your code is the older React-Router-DOM v4/5 syntax but you have specified React-Router-DOM v6 as a dependency.

## Using React-Router-DOM v4/5

If you want to continue using your current code then you'll need to downgrade the `react-router-dom` dependency.

- Uninstall the current v6 version: `npm uninstall --save react-router-dom`
- Install latest v5: `npm install --save react-router-dom@5`

## Using React-Router-DOM v6

If you want to use the current version of `react-router-dom` then you'll need to fix several breaking changes.

- There is no longer any `Switch` component, it was replaced by the `Routes` component.
- The `Route` component API was changed a bit as well, there is no longer any `component` (*and `render` and `children` function prop*), replaced by a single `element` prop taking a `React.ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX, value.
- The `useHistory` hook was removed, replaced by a `useNavigate` hook that returns a `navigate` function instead of the `history` object.

Update `App` to import and use the `Routes` component. Render the routed content correctly on the `element` prop.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Landing from "./pages/landing";
import List from "./pages/toc";
import About from "./pages/about";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Landing />} />
          <Route path="/table-of-contents" element={<List />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Replace the `useHistory` hook with the `useNavigate` hook in the routed components.

Landing

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "/src/styles/hero.css";

const Landing = () => {
  const [typingComplete, setTypingComplete] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleClick = () => {
    // Navigate to the '/table-of-contents' route when clicked
    navigate("/table-of-contents");
  };

  const handleTypingComplete = () => {
    setTypingComplete(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="landing" onClick={handleClick}>
      <h1
        className="title typing-animation glow-text"
        onAnimationEnd={handleTypingComplete}
      >
        John Doe
      </h1>
      <h2 className={`subtitle ${typingComplete ? "fade-in glow-text" : ""}`}>
        <span>
          <em>Click</em> to get started
        </span>
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Landing;
```

Toc

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import logo from "../pictures/trace.svg";
import "../styles/hero.css";
import "../styles/toc.css";
import Card from "../components/card";

const List = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  // Function to handle card click and navigate to a specific route
  const handleCardClick = (route) => {
    navigate(route); // Navigate to the specified route
  };

  return (
    <div className="toc">
      <h1 className="h1 toc-heading">Table Of Contents</h1>
      <div className="cards-container">
        {/* Add onClick handlers to the cards */}
        <Card
          title="1"
          className="item"
          content="About Me"
          onClick={() => handleCardClick("/about-me")} // Navigate to "/about-me" route
        />
        <Card
          title="2"
          className="item"
          content="Resume"
          onClick={() => handleCardClick("/resume")} // Navigate to "/resume" route
        />
        <Card
          title="3"
          className="item"
          content="Projects"
          onClick={() => handleCardClick("/projects")} // Navigate to "/projects" route
        />
        <Card
          title="4"
          className="item"
          content="Contact"
          onClick={() => handleCardClick("/contact")} // Navigate to "/contact" route
        />
      </div>
      <div className="logo-container">
        <img alt="" src={logo} width="90" height="60" className="logo" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default List;
```

You may want to read through the [Upgrading from v5](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5) migration guide for complete details for all the breaking changes in v6, and review the [Main Concepts](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts) for a high-level overview of the new features.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I was able to get the website working!